# Adding core-icon-button in <div tool> in Polymer core-scaffold

Tags: polymer

I want to add core-icon-button (e.g. "+" icon) at the end of the toolbar of core-scaffold, that is, inside of

> < div tool >

How can I do that? 
The "+" icon should be shown at the end of the toolbar in any width of the page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `core-scaffold` element is composed by 3 `content` areas:

1. `navigation`: everything you put inside an element with the attribute `navigation` or `nav` is then injected as the content for a `core-drawer-panel`
2. `tool` : here the `tool` attribute is used and the content of the `tool` element is used as the content for a `core-toolbar` inside a `core-header-panel`
3. the rest of the content is displayed in the center of the page

So to answer your question:

```
<div tool>
  <div>My Main Content Title in the Toolbar</div>
  <core-icon-button icon="add" on-tap="{{addAction}}"></core-icon-button>
</div>
```

More info on the [Building single page apps using web components](https://www.polymer-project.org/articles/spa.html) article on the Polymer website, or by digging into the [code of the element](https://github.com/Polymer/core-scaffold/blob/master/core-scaffold.html)

Comment: You are welcome! Please mark it as an answer if my comment answered you question so that other people can quickly find it